# How can I get a part of partfile?

Tags: matlab

This is probably a very simple question, but I am not able to find a straightforward solution.

```
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts('/xaaa/Data/Q2/CONUS/2002/PRECIPRATE.20020401.000000.tif')
```

Obviously, `fileparts` gives `/xaaa/Data/Q2/CONUS/2002/`

But I only want to access `/xaaa/Data/Q2/CONUS/` and disregard the last section.

One way to do it is simply count the letters parthstr(1:20). But there must be an  elegant alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most robust way to get a parent folder is to use `'..'` to access the folder above a provided folder. This is because it is independent of whether you specify an absolute or relative path as the input.

```
parent = fullfile(folder, '..');
```

In your case, since you have a filename and you want to get the parent, you can add a 'fileparts' call to that to get the direct parent folder, then pass it to the above.

```
parent = fullfile(fileparts(filename), '..');
```

This is more robust because it allows you to specify a relative file path such as `2002/PRECIPRATE.20020401.000000.tif` which could fail if you tried to call `fileparts` multiple times.

If you only have a filename (with no directories because you're in the folder where the file is), you can use `which` to get an absolute path to the file.

```
parent = fullfile(fileparts(which(filename)), '..');
```

Comment: `fileparts()` doesn't fail if you pass relative paths, but it may return empty strings once the process has exhausted the base filepath.  e.g. `fileparts(``)` simply returns an empty string.

Comment: @gariepy So a silent failure :)

Comment: I guess it's like the famous quote "The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil functions is for good functions to return empty strings." :)

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to repeat the use of `fileparts()`:

```
>> [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts('/xaaa/Data/Q2/CONUS/2002/PRECIPRATE.20020401.000000.tif');
>> [parent_pathstr, name, ~] = fileparts(pathstr)
parent_pathstr = 
        /xaaa/Data/Q2/CONUS
name =
        2002
```

Note: using the tilde `~` just ignores the file extension for the second call to `fileparts()` because you don't expect an extension.

Comment: You don't need the `~`. You can simply omit the last output argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are three answers proposed already, but I do believe there's a better solution. I would match `.*(?=/.*/)` pattern using `regexp`, like this:

```
>> originalPath = '/xaaa/Data/Q2/CONUS/2002/PRECIPRATE.20020401.000000.tif';
>> res = char(regexp(originalPath, '.*(?=/.*/)', 'match'))
res =
/xaaa/Data/Q2/CONUS
```

If you need to go n levels deeper, just keep adding `.*/` for each level, e.g.

```
>> res = char(regexp(originalPath, '.*(?=/.*/.*/)', 'match'))
res =
/xaaa/Data/Q2
```

For the **OS-agnistic** version, or if your path contains some mixture of back-slashes and forward-slashes, you can use the following regex: `'.*(?=[/\\].*[/\\])'`. Once again, to go several levels deper, just add an extra `.*[/\\]` for each level.

The benefit over using `strsplit` and `fileparts` is that you don't need to iterate anything - you get the answer with one simple regex.

Regarding `..` - I myself used this solution for a long time for generating Matlab Path dynamically. However Matlab is sometimes not able to handle breakpoints correctly in the files that have `..` in their path. To be exact, if you place a breakpoint in such a file, Matlab would ignore it unless there's another breakpoint that is triggered first (which is not in a file with `..` in path).

It obviously handles relative paths as well.

Comment: Could you include a OS-agnostic version?

Comment: @Suever, added the version that matches either forward-slashes, or back-slashes. That can be helpful on WIndows as well, and should also be OS-agnostic. Let me know if you have any issues with it,